# Replace Getdate() with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

We have a job with couple of steps and almost all of the steps use `getdate()`, but instead we want to get the date from a specific table and column. The table includes only two columns `status` as ready (doesn't change) and `statusdate` (dynamic). The plan is to create a stored procedure and replace the `getdate()` with that stored procedure.

How do I write the stored procedure? How do I declare a variable?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_DATE
    @StatusDate DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT StatusDate 
    FROM [DB_Name].[dbo].[Table_Name]
    WHERE status = ready 
END
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just join to this table or bring it in via a subquery?

Comment: What if the table contains more than one row? This question is lacking some details that makes any attempt to answer it nothing more than a guess. Please fill in the gaps.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Side note: if procedure SP_DATE exists in the database [DB_NAME] you (or someone else) will regret the use of 3 part names some day. If in a different database, you will regret not using synonyms (or something else) to facilitate system installation without forcing the use of specific database names.

Answer (score 1):

Your jobs use `getdate()` *function* therefore in order to replace it with custom programmatic object you should use *function* as well and not a stored procedure. With a function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StatusDate ()
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT
      StatusDate
    FROM Table_Name
    WHERE status = 'ready')
END
```

you can replace getdate directly

```
SELECT
  id
FROM Your_Job_List yjl
WHERE yjl.aDate < dbo.StatusDate()--getdate()
```

yet there are some questions to the design. One biggest single task of RDBMS is joining tables and perhaps a query similar to next one might be better

```
SELECT
  id
FROM Your_Job_List yjl
    ,Table_Name tn
WHERE yjl.aDate < tn.StatusDate
AND tn.status = 'ready'
```

Comment: Using a function is way more versatile than calling an SP, so this approach is better for the OP.

Comment: IMHO OP belongs to data access layer and up but storage itself should strive for as close to SQL as possible. Still I agree that if MSSQL has some nice features programmers should use them. Wisely.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spRunNextDate
AS 
BEGIN

  --SET NOCOUNT ON 

   declare @runDate datetime 
   select @runDate = MIN(StatusDate)
     from [DB_Name].[dbo].[Table_Name] 
    where [status] = 'ready'

   IF (@runDate IS NULL) 
   BEGIN
      PRINT 'NO Dates in Ready State.'
      RETURN 0
   END

   PRINT 'Will Run Date of '  + CAST(@runDate as varchar(20)) 

   -- Notice the MIN  or MAX usage above to get only one date per "run"


END      
GO
```

There are huge holes and questions raised in my presumptuous sp above, but it might get you to thinking about why your question implies that there is no parameter.    You are going to need a way to mark the day "done" or else it will be run over and over.